# How to implement update subcategory on the basis of category in JSP Spring MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, jsp

I am trying to update subcategory on the basis of category id. In the below JavaScript, I am trying to get subcategory data on the basis of the subcategory id and corresponding to that subcategory id I want to populate my all fields autofilled. I am getting undefined data in data.response.categoryid.name.

```
<script>
function updatecategory(subcategoryid){
          document.getElementById('cid').value = subcategoryid;
          var url = "../api/getsubpopup";
          $.post(url,{ 
              subcategoryid : subcategoryid,
              }, function(data, status) { 
                if (data.status == "OK") { 
                    if (data.statusCode == 1) {
                        document.getElementById("edmaincategory").value = data.response.categoryid.name; 
                        document.getElementById("edsubcategory").value = data.response.name;
                        var subcategorystatus = data.response.status;
                        if(subcategorystatus == 1){
                            edactivestatus.checked = true;
                        }else{
                            edinactivestatus.checked = true;
                        }
                    } else {
                         var error = data.responseMessage;
                        swal(error, "", "error");
                    }
                } else {
                         var error = data.responseMessage;
                        swal(error, "", "error");
                }
            });
      }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi show output of `data` .

Comment: I have dropdown. In that, list is showing empty.

Comment: do `console.log(data)` inside your `function(data, status) {` see what it gives

Comment: I checked in that way also. I am getting responses properly and correctly. But, I am not getting my category name in the dropdown.

Comment: please can you show data output ?